# Make apple script code work on any laptop (not need the user's name)

Tags: macos, generics, applescript

I have a simple code of deleting a file and making a folder. But how do I make it run on any laptop because everyone's user name is different. I know it has something to do with "~" but i'm not sure where. 
The code below works properly but how do I make sure it can run on any mac:

```
try
  tell application "Finder"
    delete ((POSIX file "/Users/myname/Desktop/thefile.txt"))
    make new folder at (POSIX file ("/Users/myname/Desktop")) with properties {name:"thefolder"}
  end tell
on error
  display dialog ("That didnt work") buttons {":("}
end try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax independent of the user name is much simpler since the desktop folder of the current user is the *root* folder of the `Finder`

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        delete file "thefile.txt"
        make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"thefolder"}
    end tell
on error
    display dialog ("That didnt work") buttons {":("}
end try
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I gave the desktop just an example. I actually want to do this operation in a folder in the library. So how can I do this?

Comment: The path to the user library is `path to library folder from user domain`.

Comment: How about in the library a folder called messages. How to reach that?

Comment: `(path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Messages:"`. It can be  used directly with the `folder` keyword

Comment: I want to delete a file called "attachments.txt" in that messages folder. How to do that?

Comment: `delete file ((path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Messages:attachments.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can also     

set username to ""

        tell application "System Events"

            set username to full name of current user

        end tell

         try
          tell application "Finder"
            delete ((POSIX file "/Users/username/Desktop/thefile.txt"))
            make new folder at (POSIX file ("/Users/username/Desktop")) with properties {name:"thefolder"}
          end tell
        on error
          display dialog ("That didnt work") buttons {":("}
        end try
```